# Como carregar um vídeo em uma tela?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou fazendo um aplicativo no Android Studio onde tenho a tela principal(MainActivity) que tem um menu com vários links e um deles chama um Fragment(VideoFragment) onde quando carregado deve mostrar um vídeo(youtube e local) com descrição, alguém pode dar uma ajuda? obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Acho que isso aqui pode te ajudar:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma webView, por exemplo:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webview_compontent );

String playVideo= "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"640\" height=\"385\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/bIPcobKMB94\" frameborder=\"0\"></body></html>"

myWebView.loadData(playVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Abraços.